# Version error on SAGA NextGen on QGIS and MacOS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, saga, mac, macos

I am trying to use SAGA NextGen on QGIS and when I try to run a program I get an error message saying that I need to update the SAGA binaries to 9.1. I am using QGIS 3.34 on MacOS.

Is there any way around this problem on macOS? I know this question has already been asked but, I would prefer to get a concrete answer from a macOS user as I seem to read on the WWW that the same solution for Windows does not seem to work for macOS.

Comment: Try downloading latest binaries, then change the path in Settings/Options/Processing/Providers/SAGANG/SAGA folder